# Windows Print Spooling

Tags: printing

I have paused a print queue and using Windows Explorer, am monitoring the `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` directory. When I  print documents to the print queue, I notice the creation of a `.spl` file and `.shd` file. From quickly googling, it looks like the print job is the `.spl` file and the `.shd` file is settings.

Can I confirm exactly **what** the `.spl` file contains? Is it the actual file being printed after being processed by the print driver? So once the `.shd` file has directed the job, the `.spl` file is the thing that is actually *printed*?

Comment: Might be worth a read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language

Comment: Your better of looking into postscript files as spl is likely closed source, easiest way to teSt is open the file in notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the SPL files are the actual spool (print job) files.

You can check by setting the port of your printer to "File:" and printing something. You're asked to give a file and location (i.e. C:\TEMP\PRINT.PRN). This file contains what is actually send to the printer. If you set the printer back to your printer-port and pause the printer and print the same thing you can compare the PRINT.PRN and .SPL file.

You can check in this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264662) what the files are for.

More on these formats [here](http://www.undocprint.org/winspool/spool_files).